# Logistic regression with binary and ordinal variables (SAS)

Tags: logistic, binary-data, ordinal-data, sas

I have survey results (n=14, small size, I know) which scored several health measures from Poor (1), Fair (2), Good (3), Very Good (4), and Excellent(5). I want to see if having a physician (0=no, 1=yes) and insurance (0=no, 1=yes) predicts the likelihood of someone reporting poorer or greater health scores. How would I do this? And in SAS? My colleague recommended I perform logistic regression.

I have only performed frequency, correlation, and linear regression in SAS so far. I am new to statistics and coding.

This is my code:

```
proc logistic data = inc.data_scores desc;
class general_health1;
model physician (event='1') = general_health1;
run;
```

general_health1 is the ordinal variable. My results seem weird (below). I know I've got this wrong somehow.

```
Analysis of Maximum Likelihood Estimates
Parameter           DF  Estimate    SE  Wald Chi-Square   Pr > ChiSq
Intercept           1    -2.1336 53.8897 0.0016        0.9684
general_health1 1   1   12.5115 149.0   0.0071         0.9331
general_health1 2   1   -8.1866 145.3   0.0032         0.9551
general_health1 3   1   -8.1866 94.7252 0.0075         0.9311
general_health1 4   1   1.7282  53.8944 0.0010         0.9744

Odds Ratio Estimates
Effect               Point Estimate   95% Wald Confidence Limits

general_health1 1 vs 5  >999.999 <0.001 >999.999
general_health1 2 vs 5  <0.001  <0.001  >999.999
general_health1 3 vs 5  <0.001  <0.001  >999.999
general_health1 4 vs 5  0.667   0.047   9.472
```

Comment: Welcome to cv, Amy! How big is your sample, and how many responses did you get, roughly, for the health groups? How large is the percentage of respondents that have a physician? It could also be a problem with your data, therefore this information is important. (admittedly I did not check your code, my SAS is rusty)

Comment: @Ute Thank you! I have 14 complete responses. 35.71% have a physician. I appreciate your help!

Comment: The minimum sample size needed just to estimate the intercept in a binary logistic model is 96, i.e., if you have zero covariates.  The more covariates you have the higher the needed sample size.  See [this](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/lrm.html#sec-lrm-n).

Comment: You have too few people. This has resulted in complete separation.

Also, you are treating the IV as categorical, not ordinal. Methods for ordinal variable IVs aren't common, but one is optimal scaling.  Still that won't be enough to solve the sample size problem.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you stated n=14 in the start. What about presenting your data as a graph, or just a table? If you had many more responses, you could consider a chisquare test

Comment: P-values are not appropriate with this sample size.  Use confidence intervals, which will be scarily and honestly wide.